# deleting rows with missing values and negative values based on a column

Tags: r, row, delete-row

I have an imported csv file called `file`.I am trying to delete the rows that have negative and N/A values in the column `varq`.

I have used the code below for the N/A values but I will now like to remove the negative.

```
 file$varq[!is.na(file$varq)]
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
 file <-  file[as.numeric(as.character(file$varq)) > 0,]
```